# Find path for file

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have folder tree, were in each folder there are some files (.xls or .CSV). I want to know path of that file and need to create folder on system date in that. and move file to concern folder.
And next time when that script will run it will check only till old folder and will not check folder having SYStemdate.

Here is the code which I created but stuck(ACC is the path which is not fix for Subfolders.).

```
@Echo Off
::Variable for folder path
::Set AAC= d:\A\CC
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do Echo AA %%i

::for /r D:\A\CC %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="Lists.txt" set AAC=%%~dpa
Echo As %i%

:: SDate=DAYMONTHYEAR FORMAT of Systemdate
set SDate=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%

if not exist %i%\%SDate% mkdir %i%\%SDate%

move %i%\* %i%\%SDate%

::for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir d:\%Folder% /b /s') do copy "%%a %%b\*" "%Folder%\%SDate%\*
::for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir d:\A\*.txt /b /s') do set Ag=%%a

set "AAC="
Echo Now %AAC%
```

Comment: Since your description appears not quite clear, it would be helpful if you show an example of your folder structure... What is the value of variable `%i%`?

Comment: Folder Structure is d:\A\AA\BB\\*\\*.xls 
Parent folder is fix but I may have multiple Subfolder depending on excel file name. So my requirement is to create one folder in each BB on System date and move respective file in that System Date folder. Now problem is like BB I may have CC, DD and EE folder inside Folder Name AA. Script should create folder on date in BB,CC,DD and EE. And Next time when script will execute it will check till BB-EE only and not subfolder in side this BB - EE.
I hope it is clear now..!

Comment: And in i I am trying to store folder path of one file at a time, so that can create new sub-folder inside particular folder.

Comment: @Ashu please put the pertinent information into your opening post not in the comments section. There is an edit facility for doing just that. If you do not make your information easier to follow, your question is likely to be closed or remain unanswered.